# Ignorar DataMember dependiendo de un valor

Tags: c#, wcf

Tengo un servicio desarrollado con `WCF`, en este servicio hago un llamado a un `stored procedure`, este me devuelve 4 campos : `id`, `id_visita` ,`fecha`, `observaciones`. Puede ocurrir el caso que el campo `id_visita` venga null y esto se debe a que no se ha hecho la visita correspondiente, por ende el valor `fecha` es de un dia anterior a hoy y el campo `observaciones` tambien es nulo.

En mi servicio hago lo siguiente :

```
int gestion_ruta_visita_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id_visita"]);
if (gestion_ruta_visita_id != 0)
{
   //Si es que ya fue visitada, obtener detalles de la visita
   gestionRuta.estado = 1;
   gestionRuta.gestion_ruta_visita_fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["fecha"]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
   gestionRuta.gestion_ruta_visita_observaciones = Convert.ToString(dr["observaciones"]);
}
```

En este codigo obtengo si tiene o no la `id_visita` , si es distinta a 0, quiere decir que la visita ya se realizo por ende mi objeto `gestionRuta` tiene lo siguiente :

```
[DataMember]
public string gestion_ruta_visita_fecha { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public string gestion_ruta_visita_observaciones { get; set; }
```

Estos campos SOLO se llenan cuando el `id_visita` es distinto de 0, pero en el otro caso, que sea 0, no quiero que en mi json aparezcan como null, simplemente que no aparezcan.

Resultado actual :

```
"rutas": [
  {
    "estado": 1,
    "gestion_ruta_codigo_sala": "3200007286",
    "gestion_ruta_direccion_sala": "La Florida",
    "gestion_ruta_latitud_sala": "-33.4141632",
    "gestion_ruta_longitud_sala": "-70.627686",
    "gestion_ruta_nombre_sala": "Jumbo La Florida",
    "gestion_ruta_programacion_fecha": "25-05-2015",
    "gestion_ruta_programacion_id": 391,
    "gestion_ruta_visita_fecha": "02-06-2016 16:11",
    "gestion_ruta_visita_observaciones": "Sin observaciones"
  },
  {
    "estado": 2,
    "gestion_ruta_codigo_sala": "3200007286",
    "gestion_ruta_direccion_sala": "La Florida",
    "gestion_ruta_latitud_sala": "-33.4141632",
    "gestion_ruta_longitud_sala": "-70.627686",
    "gestion_ruta_nombre_sala": "Jumbo La Florida",
    "gestion_ruta_programacion_fecha": "27-05-2015",
    "gestion_ruta_programacion_id": 392,
    "gestion_ruta_visita_fecha": null,
    "gestion_ruta_visita_observaciones": null
  },
```

Resultado esperado :

```
"rutas": [
  {
    "estado": 1,
    "gestion_ruta_codigo_sala": "3200007286",
    "gestion_ruta_direccion_sala": "La Florida",
    "gestion_ruta_latitud_sala": "-33.4141632",
    "gestion_ruta_longitud_sala": "-70.627686",
    "gestion_ruta_nombre_sala": "Jumbo La Florida",
    "gestion_ruta_programacion_fecha": "25-05-2015",
    "gestion_ruta_programacion_id": 391,
    "gestion_ruta_visita_fecha": "02-06-2016 16:11",
    "gestion_ruta_visita_observaciones": "Sin observaciones"
  },
  {
    "estado": 2,
    "gestion_ruta_codigo_sala": "3200007286",
    "gestion_ruta_direccion_sala": "La Florida",
    "gestion_ruta_latitud_sala": "-33.4141632",
    "gestion_ruta_longitud_sala": "-70.627686",
    "gestion_ruta_nombre_sala": "Jumbo La Florida",
    "gestion_ruta_programacion_fecha": "27-05-2015",
    "gestion_ruta_programacion_id": 392
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado una solución

```
[DataContract]
public class GestionRuta
```

Definir como `DataContract` mi clase y los elementos que no quiero que retorne cuando sean nulos como `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]`

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public string gestion_ruta_visita_fecha { get; set; }
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
public string gestion_ruta_visita_observaciones { get; set; }
```

Si hay otra mejor solución la espero :D

Comment: Hay que tener cuidado con esa propiedad. Como su nombre lo dice, especifica que en caso de que el campo tenga su valor por defecto no lo serialice. Si bien te funcionó, segun [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347792.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) no es una buena práctica poner en falso esa propiedad.

Comment: @PabloClaus muchas gracias por tu comentario!, lo que estoy buscando es una buena practica para este caso, si tienes otra solucion, por favor no dudes en dejarla

Comment: Acá encontré algo que te puede servir. El problema es que hay que hacer unas modificaciones en el diseño importantes. Quizás la complejidad de tu problema no lo justifique (Algunos lo usan para evitar enviar objetos complejos). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091785/dynamically-ignore-data-members-from-getting-serialized

Comment: @PabloClaus voy a echar un vistazo!, gracias por la ayuda